# How to update the hostname for a computer

Tags: livecd, hostname, lubuntu

On my Lubuntu machine (14.04 LTS), I booted an Arch disk, to have a look around, and now my hostname on my Lubuntu box is stuck as `archiso`.

My hostname is set to what I want it to be, but I can't ssh to it at that hostname, I have to use `archiso`

My router thinks my Lubuntu machine still has the hostname `archiso`, when it should be `blu`

How can I fix this? I'm using a BT Home Hub 3.

Comment: I'm confused: are you now running Ubuntu or Arch? Do you want to update the hostname on your running computer, or to save the hostname across reboots?

Comment: On Linux, I think the hostname is defined in `/etc/hostname`. Though it may be used in other places. But I agree with Gilles, your question is not clear.

Comment: Sorry, I have tried to clarify my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all I had to do was restart my HomeHub. I guess the HomeHub reloads the DHCP tables when it restarts. Thank you Tim for prompting me in this direction.

Answer (score 0):

hostname is generally stored in `/etc/hostname` and also referenced in `/etc/hosts`

Do these files contain the name **archisio**? if so, change to whatever you'd prefer.

Comment: Sorry, my question was unclear. My hostname is set to what I want, but I can't `ssh` to the computer using that hostname, the hostname I have to use is `archiso`.

Answer (score 0):

Your router stored the hostame... (in the dhcp table?) you can try to clear that.

What might also be useful are the `Host` and `Hostame` directives in [`~/.ssh/config`](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Configure_openSSH#Personal_configuration_file).

Comment: Thank you, after looking through forum posts elsewhere about clearing dhcp tables, I decided to restart the router, and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you have booted into a liveCD and you want to set the hostname of the running instance to **archiso**, you can run:`hostname archiso`

If you want to change the hostname of the lubuntu instance, you need to mount the filesystem and edit etc/hosts, etc/hostname

If you need to ssh from another host on your home network, presuming network & SSH is configured you need your client to be able to resolve "archiso" to the ip address of your liveCD instance. The easiest way to do that is to add "archiso" and its ip address to /etc/hosts on the client (or c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts if your ssh client is running on Windows)

Comment: None of this answers my question, which was about how to get the **router** to recognise the fact that my hostname was **no longer** `archiso`. Sorry if I was unclear